# Python Tabulate formats characters as separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, tabulate

Using pandas, I am reading in a tab delimited file that looks like this:

[image]

with the following code:

```
pantry_file = pd.read_csv('/PantryList.txt', sep='\t')
```

Based on user input, I want to print out a nice looking table of all Items in this file. I am using tabulate to do this. The code looks like this:

```
print(tabulate(pantry_file.loc[: , "ITEM"], tablefmt='psql', headers=['Pantry Item'], showindex=False))
```

However, the resulting output treats each character as a column:

[image]

Wheres a traditional print statement looks like this:

[image]

My question is, why is tabulate treating each letter as a column, and how can I correct this?

Other info: Python 3.6 using Spyder through Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
print(tabulate(list(map(lambda x:[x], pantry_file.loc[:, "ITEM"])), tablefmt='psql', headers=['Pantry Item'], showindex=False))
```

output:

```
+---------------+
| Pantry Item   |
|---------------|
| Butter        |
| Salt          |
| Chicken       |
| Beef Broth    |
| Pepper        |
| Milk          |
+---------------+
```

Comment: That works... thanks! Would you mind explaining what exactly its doing? I am not very familiar with lambda expressions... May help others too. Thanks!

Comment: It's converting from ['Butter', 'Salt', ...] to [['Butter'], ['Salt'], ...]   tabulate needs to have a list of lists, or it splits the words